# Nginx enable cache for specific URI

Tags: nginx

I have a basic rewrite happening in my main block:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php.php?$is_args$args
}
```

Now i would like to remove caching from all requests that starts with /api/. 
I was tempted to use "if" in my location block but according to nginx doc that is not a good practice.

I also try to nest a block hoping there would be some inheritence happening but i don't think i got that right as /api requests to not get handed to PHP.

```
location / {
  location /api/ {
     expires -1;
  }
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php.php?$is_args$args
}
```

So what would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location /api/ {
  expires epoch;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

I've removed `$args`. You could get them in PHP from fastcgi params, so there is no need to have them here.

Comment: That works but I'd rather not repeat the try statment. Are you aware of a way to do so ? No the double php extension was a typo. As for the args i just copied that snippet from a post somewhere and it works fine. Do you think it's better without the is_args check ?

Comment: No. Igor Sysoev (author of nginx) recommends keep configuration simple and do not afraid repeating. Especially such simple one line string.

Comment: In my opinion, there is no reason to add args at all. PHP could get all the parameters from REQUEST_URI. See http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Front_Controller_Pattern_based_packages for example.

Comment: Ok i went that way, so all good then. Do you by any chance have a reference to where Igor Sysoev mention this ? 
About the arg thing, thanks for the tip, i'll give it a try.

Comment: actually i do need the `?$args` as otherwise the get parameters do not seems to follow.